# Browser cannot read height value of an image

Tags: javascript, image

Since a couple of months and maybe longer i'm struggling with what seems to me a fault in javascript code, but i can't nail it down. Maybe some of you can give me a hint.

starting with the following code which one can easily find on the net:

```
<head>
    <title>Slideshow</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function resizeImage()
        {
            var window_height = document.body.clientHeight
            var window_width  = document.body.clientWidth
            var image_width   = document.images[0].width
            var image_height  = document.images[0].height
            var height_ratio  = image_height / window_height
            var width_ratio   = image_width / window_width
            if (height_ratio > width_ratio)
            {
                document.images[0].style.height = "100%"
                document.images[0].style.width  = "auto"
            }
            else
            {
                document.images[0].style.width  = "100%"
                document.images[0].style.height = "auto"
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#000000 onresize="resizeImage()">
    <img onload="resizeImage()" margin="0" border="0" src="nweshow/picture-0011.jpg">
</body>
```

Now this works fine for just one image on my webpage.

But when i use this code as part of my script for showing images of etchings, silk-screens, drawings, etc. in very different aspect, things go wrong.

The point is that the images are shown each at a time [say 5 seconds], with no user interaction whatsoever, except for pressing key F11 for getting a full screen image outside the browser window, which i prefer. The total script reads now:

```
<head>
    <title>Slideshow</title>
    <script>
        function resizeImage()
        {
            var window_height = document.body.clientHeight;
            var window_width  = document.body.clientWidth;
            var image_width   = document.images[0].width;
            var image_height  = document.images[0].height;
            var height_ratio  = image_height / window_height;
            var width_ratio   = image_width / window_width;

            if (height_ratio > width_ratio)
            {
                document.images[0].width  = "auto";
                document.images[0].height = "100%";
            }
            else
            {
                document.images[0].width  = "100%";
                document.images[0].height = "auto";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor=#000000 onresize="resizeImage()">

    <script>
        var curindex=0
        var rimages=new Array()

        for ( i=0;i<54;i++)
        {
            rimages[i]="nweshow/picture-00"+(i+1)+".jpg"
        }

        var preload=new Array()

        for (n=0;n<rimages.length;n++)
        {
            preload[n]=new Image()
            preload[n].src=rimages[n]
        }

        document.write('<center><img onload="resizeImage()" name="fvds" alt="atelier" margin="0" border="0" src="' + rimages[curindex] + '"></center>')

        function rotateimage()
        {
            curindex = (curindex==rimages.length - 1) ? 0 : curindex + 1; //increment or reset
            document.images.fvds.src=rimages[curindex];
        }

        setInterval("rotateimage()", 4000)
    </script>
</body>
```

Now it is the case that only when the width_ratio is bigger than the height_ratio the image gets resized [keeping aspect-ratio], which corresponds with the "else" clause of the "if"- statement. This inmdicates that when the condition is true, the browser cannot read the height value of the image. This seems very strange to me. But when I check the output in Google chrome while the script is running, this is not confirmed. Meaning that within the img element the height and width value is addressed correctly: '' 
So the browser does not do what the script told it to do. [btw the same holds for Firefox]

Can someone give me a clue?
Any help is welcome, thanks in advance

wimsch

Comment: Have you tried google chrome script debug step by step?

Comment: Not so much related, but you are defining `i` and `n` with no `var` before them, that makes them global and that is always a bad idea...

Comment: this is exactly what I did and ment with the phrase " But when I check the output in Google chrome while the script is running, this is not confirmed. Meaning that within the img element ..." etc.

Comment: However, the crucial output " style="height: 100%; width: auto;" [indicating that the browser correctly read but did not execute these style properties according to the script] was omitted in my former answer, because I'm not so familiar with the presentation rules of the stackoverflow website.

Comment: BTW there is no problem with the pictures shown as a [sort of] slideshow sequentially [like a screensaver: no buttons, etc]. The point is, however, that I cannot get the immages -as part of a slideshow- resized full screen, which is indeed the case when an image is shown statically. Nothing else [no text] is shown on the webpage, which is not online yet. This suggests to me that there is problem with loading images dynamically: i.e. there should be moment  between the former and the next image in which the img element is not visible, just the black background.

Comment: Have to apologize for this post. There is a hidden code in the header of my webpage blocking the resizing of the image, which I did not noticed first. Sorry about this. Problem solved. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Now i'm faced with the following problem: how do i center a certain [unknown] image exactly in the middle of the screen [also full screen]? Especially when image_height < window_height just in case image_width = window_width ["else"]]. BTW can somebody explain why my solution [see code below] doesn't work? Within the browser the value of vspace = "0", which means that the arithmetic expression is not recognized, but why not? Thanks again!!

Comment: function resizeImage()
    {
 etc...
 var aspect_ratio  = image_height / image_width

 if (height_ratio > width_ratio)
 {
  document.images[0].style.width  = "auto";
  document.images[0].style.height = "100%";
 }
 else
 {
  var new_vspace = Math.round((window_height - window_width*aspect_ratio) / 2);
  document.images[0].style.width  = "100%";
  document.images[0].style.height = "auto";
  document.images[0].vspace="new_vspace";
 }
    }

    </script>
    </head>